# Excel cells matching in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I want to use a number in a cell of my main excel sheet and use it to search for a specific line in another excel file that start with this number. After, the program needs to use the value of a specific cell in this line for a cell in my main excel sheet.

EX : value of the first cell in my sheet : **6.02** . Now the program need to find this value in a column of another file. The line that start with **6.02** contain a cell with the value **dog**. The value **dog** need to go inside a cell next to the first one that contain **6.02**.

I need your help because I know nothing about VBA. I'm starting today!

Thank you very much !!

Comment: You don't need VBA, google VLOOKUP spreadsheet function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a VLOOKUP between two books. The guts of the equation are below. You wont actually type in the '[book2]SheetName' portion, this will need to reflect the name of your other workbook and the sheet that you are looking at within that book.

A2 = Look up value (in your example 6.02)
X1 = Column the return value is (in your example "dog")
X2 = Column Index Number (Of if you are not starting from A it represents the (Index Col of Value - Index of Look up Value) + 1

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[Book2]SheetName'!$A$X1,X2,0)
```